# Different LDAP Filters for Separate Services in SSSD

Tags: pam, sssd, rhel8

I'd like to use LDAP in SSSD for two separate services on the same server. Specifically, I'd like to use one LDAP group for SSH access and a separate LDAP group for access to a web portal. It only appears I can do that through the "ldap_access_filter" parameter in sssd.conf. Is there a way I can use separate LDAP filters depending upon context? I'm using RHEL 8. Authentication is currently working on both, just not with the groups I want.